# What kind of complexity does SonarQube use?

Tags: sonarqube, metrics

In the past, Sonar used cyclomatic complexity. On their website, they mention Cognitive complexity..but in their documentation, there is just "Complexity" measure but with the same "shortcomings" of the cyclomatic one (e.g. increasing by 1 for each CASE in a switch). 
Which one is the one used now,then?

Answer (score 2):

The "Complexity" metrics currently being calculated are Cyclomatic Complexity.

It is worth noting that recent Code Analyzer versions compute the correct Cyclomatic Complexity value - versus the previous combination of Cyclomatic and Essential Complexities.

Cognitive Complexity metrics aren't available at this writing, but should be available "soon".

**UPDATE**
Cognitive Complexity is currently available as a metric in SonarJava, SonarJS, SonarC#, SonarSwift, and SonarC-Family (C/C++, Objective-C)

Comment: See my update @venerik. Just be sure to use the latest version of each analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Currently it's Cognitive Complexity

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here:
https://blog.sonarsource.com/cognitive-complexity-because-testability-understandability/

Cognitive Complexity for Java, JavaScript, C#, and C/C++/Objective-C.

I understand that (at this moment) other code languages plugins implement Cyclomatic Complexity as they are not migrated to the new calculation method.